# Echo bash variable by delimiter

Tags: bash

I swear I came across a way to do this the other day, but don't remember it exactly:

```
a="blah,test"
echo ${a[,1]}
blah
```

Basically, it seemed it was setting a delimiter in an array, and specifying what part of the variable to use. Basically the same as this in awk:

```
echo $a | awk -F "," '{print $1}'
```

Was I taking crazy pills, or is something like this possible?  I need this because I am echoing out text from the variable in the middle of a sentence, and need to choose which part to use.

Answer (score 4):

```
a="blah,test"
IFS=',' read -a array <<< "$a"
echo "${array[1]}"
```

[`IFS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables) is input field separator, `read` uses it to split the line into words see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html). With `-a` words are assigned to sequential indices of the array. `<<<` is [here strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) causes `$a` to be expanded and supplied to the `read` command.

Comment: Try and add more to the answer then just code.  Try and explain what the code block is doing, so the poster can learn from it and gain some knowledge.